# What is the syntax for including multiple navigation properties in Entity Framework?

Tags: .net, asp.net, entity-framework, entity

I am querying an Entity(**Applicant**) which has multiple navigation properties, need to include two navigation properties (Worker and StatusType) in the include part of the query.

Tried including one property Worker as **.include("Worker")** this works, but when I use **.include("Worker, StatusType")** to get both the navigation properties the query fails with the message 'invalid include path'.

What is the syntax for including multiple navigation properties in Entity Framework?

Comment: I would use the generic variants: `.Include(a => a.Worker).Include(a => a.StatusType)`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use

```
Include("Worker").Include("StatusType")
```

Comment: You can also use `Include(x => x.Worker)` which is less error prone.

Answer (score 6):

Or if it is a subproperty of the property you are including try

```
.Include("Worker.StatusType")
```

Comment: You can also use `Include(x => x.Worker.StatusType)` which is less error prone.

Answer (score 2):

```
for example we have two class :

public class Address 
{
 [Required]
 public int ProvinceId { get; set; }

 [ForeignKey(nameof(ProvinceId))]
 public Province Province { get; set; }

}

public class Province 
{
 [StringLength(50)]
 [Required]
 public string Name { get; set; }
}

 //Now if you want to include province use code below : 

 .Include(x => x.Address).ThenInclude(x => x.Province)
```